# Difference between Content-Disposition: Form-data and attachment

Tags: rest, post, https, http-headers, content-disposition

I am building out an apache HttpClient for a REST service I have, and a app that will be using my service is sending a POST request using `"content-disposition: attachment; name="file"; filename="file.txt"`.

Currently my Client is using `"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"`.  Currently my request is multipart/mixed, where I am sending a file, and JSON.

Ideally I would need to have my client using the attachment one, but after much research, I have not found anything meaningful.  What exactly is the difference between the two content-dispositions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachment is for responses, form-data is for requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: So then it is not possible to have my client send an content-disposition: attachment request to my Spring service?

Comment: @sparky123 Afaik. attachment is for opening a file download dialog. But I would check its RFC to be completely certain if I were you.